# Yii2 cannot get date from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have a simple app like guestbook, and I'm using yii2 with REST controller.

My model `Message` is:

```
class Message extends ActiveRecord 
{
    public $created_at;

public static function tableName()
{
    return "{{%messages}}";
}

public function behaviors()
{
    // return [
    //     'timestamp' => [
    //      'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
    //      'attributes' => [
    //          ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => 'created_at',
    //          ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'updated_at'
    //      ],
    //      'value' => function() { return time(); }
    //     ]
    // ];
    return [TimestampBehavior::className()];
}

public function beforeSave($insert) 
{
    if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
        $this->created_at = time('U');
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['username', 'message'], 'required']
    ];
}

public function fields()
{
    return [
        'id',
        'username',
        'message',
        'created_at'
    ];
}
```

}

and my REST controller `MessageController` is:

```
class MessageController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'frontend\models\Message';

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return parent::behaviors();
    }

}
```

**I have fetched data via JSON and value `created_at` always equals zero.**
In my mysql5 I have column `created_at`

```
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

From terminal command `select * from messages` return result with `created_at` value `2015-07-01 17:57:39`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already the column `created_at` in database table `message`  you don't need a new field created_at in Message Model. This field in the model hidden the field in database. Remove this field from model.